# changing a value of a term while iterating a HashSet

Tags: c#, hashset

i am using a HashSet in order to avoid having two (or more)items with the same value inside my collection , on my work i need to iterate over my hashset and remove its values but unfortunatly i cant do so , what i am trying to do is:

```
string newValue = "";
HashSet<string> myHashSet;
myHashSet = GetAllValues(); // lets say there is a function which fill the hashset
foreach (string s in myHashSet)
{
       newValue = func(s) // lets say that func on some cases returns s as  it was and
       if(s != newValue)  // for some cases returns another va
       {
             myHashSet.Remove(s);
             myHashSet.Add(newValue);
       }

}
```

thanks in advance for your kind help

Comment: You cannot 'fill' a HashSet that way. Your `= new HashSet<string>();` is overwritten.

Comment: fair enough i shouldnt have made the new HashSet<string>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify the container while it's being iterated. The solution would be to project the initial set into a "modified" set using LINQ ([`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)), and create a new `HashSet` from the results of the projection.

Since if there is a `func` with the appropriate signature you can directly stick it into the `Enumerable.Select` method, and since `HashSet` has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504.aspx) that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`, it all comes down to one line:

```
var modifiedHashSet = new HashSet(myHashSet.Select(func));
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is indeed correct, but if, as in my case, you *require* modification of the same instance, you can iterate through a copy of the `HashSet`.

```
foreach (string s in myHashSet.ToArray()) // ToArray will create a copy
{
   newValue = func(s)
   if(s != newValue)
   {
         myHashSet.Remove(s);
         myHashSet.Add(newValue);
   }
}
```